# JME3 Fragment/Shader not compiling

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl, jmonkeyengine

Here is the fragment shader code (MyShaders/Shader1.frag):

```
void main(){
   gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0);
}
```

And the vertex shader code (MyShaders/Shader1.vert):

```
void main(void)
{

    gl_Position=vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);

}
```

And the .j3md material code:

```
MaterialDef Shader1 {
    MaterialParameters {
    }

    Technique {
        VertexShader GLSL100 GLSL150:   MyShaders/Shader1.frag
        FragmentShader GLSL100 GLSL150: MyShaders/Shader1.vert
    }
}
```

The error stack trace is:

```
WARNING: Bad compile of:
1   #version 110
2   #define FRAGMENT_SHADER 1
3   void main(void)
4   {
5   
6       gl_Position=vec4(1.0,1.0,1.0,0.0);
7   
8   }

May 01, 2018 3:35:57 PM com.jme3.app.LegacyApplication handleError
SEVERE: Uncaught exception thrown in Thread[jME3 Main,5,main]
com.jme3.renderer.RendererException: compile error in: ShaderSource[name=MyShaders/Shader1.vert, defines, type=Fragment, language=GLSL100]
ERROR: 0:6: Use of undeclared identifier 'gl_Position'
```

And here is the code for instantiating the material:

```
Material mat=new Material(assetManager,"MyShaders/Shader1.j3md");
```

I think that the bug is somewhere in me not passing any `gl_Position` parameters into the shader, but how do I do that?

I am using [JME3](http://jmonkeyengine.org/) and Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You switched your vertex and fragment shader filenames inside `Technique{...}`

```
Technique { 
  VertexShader GLSL100 GLSL150: MyShaders/Shader1.frag
  FragmentShader GLSL100 GLSL150: MyShaders/Shader1.vert 
}
```

should become

```
Technique { 
  VertexShader GLSL100 GLSL150: MyShaders/Shader1.vert
  FragmentShader GLSL100 GLSL150: MyShaders/Shader1.frag
}
```

Comment: :head-bash: Really.  That was kind of stupid of me.